# UINavigationController: push/pop, back button animation fading or fading+shifting?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

Recently I had a problem when pushing / popping view controller in navigation stack, I have a VC which has a back button, and I do it as:

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popCurrentVC:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 67, 31);

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:item animated:YES];
```

Then what I see is the button fades in at the correct position, but in some apps, I do see that the button transition is like, it not only fades in, but also moves from RHS to LHS, I need this effect, where should I change in order to make the button fading in as well as moving?

Thanks!